# RewardVideoListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted() in RewardedVideoAdListener

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

//Here is my code

```
package name.ratson.cordova.admob.rewardvideo;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import name.ratson.cordova.admob.AbstractExecutor;

class RewardVideoListener implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
private final RewardVideoExecutor executor;

RewardVideoListener(RewardVideoExecutor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    synchronized (executor.rewardedVideoLock) {
        executor.isRewardedVideoLoading = false;
    }

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("error", errorCode);
        data.put("reason", AbstractExecutor.getErrorReason(errorCode));
        data.put("adType", executor.getAdType());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.LOAD_FAIL", data);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("adType", executor.getAdType());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.EXIT_APP", data);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    synchronized (executor.rewardedVideoLock) {
        executor.isRewardedVideoLoading = false;
    }
    Log.w("AdMob", "RewardedVideoAdLoaded");
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.LOAD");

    if (executor.shouldAutoShow()) {
        executor.showAd(true, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.OPEN");
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.START");
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE");
    executor.clearAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("adType", executor.getAdType());
        data.put("rewardType", reward.getType());
        data.put("rewardAmount", reward.getAmount());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.fireAdEvent("admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD", data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your RewardVideoListener class is implementing RewardedVideoAdListener in interface.

In order to compile with the RewardedVideoAdListener interface you need to implement all the interface methods including RewardedVideoAdListener.

So add this to your class:

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @Bhadresh great, please mark it as the right answer so others can reference it

Comment: Headsup that it has 3 files that it should be added to, so just search the project folder for "RewardVideoListener.java"

Comment: cannot find symbol
Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 2):

For Cordova projects - TOAST was undefined.  This helped...

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
  fireAdEvent(EVENT_AD_WILLDISMISS, ADTYPE_REWARDVIDEO);
}
```